# Converting int to unicode

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to convert this (0x80 + i) where i = 1, 2, 3, 4 .... to a unicode symbol . I know that in unicode (0x80 + 1) = Ѓ but I can't do the right conversion to get this symbol in a char variable.

I also tried to get the int value of the symbol and it seems to work but only if I know what the symbol is going to be. I need some how to get a symbol every time using that equation.

```
char registered = 'Ѓ';
System.out.println(String.format("This is an int-code: %d", (int) registered));
System.out.println(String.format("And this is an hexa code: %x", (int) registered));
```

Comment: No, in Unicode U+0081 is a control character. See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf

Comment: `"\u0403"` is `Ѓ`. 0x403 = 0x80 + 0x383. For Cyrillic it suffices to do `(char)0x403`; cast an int to a char.

Comment: Why not `System.out.format`?

Comment: I cast it to char but still I have the trouble getting the symbol to a variable. When I write registered = (char)0x403; it is OK but i am using  int i = (0x80 + 1); registered = (char) i;   and this returns " ? " to registered or if I try  String.format("%x",(int)registered)); I get 403 and I cant do much with it.

Answer (score 0):

Note the value for i is 1027(in hex 0x403), not 200 (in hex 0x80).

java code:

```
char registered = 'Ѓ';
int i = (int) registered;
char registered2 = (char)i;
System.out.println("registered: " + registered);
System.out.println("i: " + i);
System.out.println("registered2: " + registered2);
```

result is:

```
registered: Ѓ
i: 1027
registered2: Ѓ
```